# Merging separate Double Click VBA events in a single worksheet

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet where I have adapted two pieces of VBA code to perform two different double click event actions.

The 1st piece of code enters a "✓" in a specific range of cells when double clicked and removes it when double clicked again:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H600,M2:V600")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If
    Cancel = True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

The 2nd piece of code enters a date/time stamp in a range of cells when double clicked:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
'Coded by SunnyKow - 16/09/2016
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine
'You can change the range here
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2:L600,Y2:Y600")) Is Nothing Then
  'Update only if cell is empty
  If Target = "" Then
    Target = Now
  End If
  Cancel = True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrorRoutine:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

Because you cannot have two double click events in single worksheet (as separate VBA code), how do I merge these two pieces of VBA so that it is a single piece of code with two distinct actions based on the cell range selected. Would appreciate any help to resolve this.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like an if statement will do the trick

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2:L600,Y2:Y600")) Is Nothing Then
  'Update only if cell is empty
  If Target = "" Then
    Target = Now
  End If
  Cancel = True
ElseIf  Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H600,M2:V600")) Is Nothing Then
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If
    Cancel = True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrorRoutine:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Hi. Thank you for responding. I copied the VBA code into my worksheet and it does not seem to work.  Neither the double click to add the "✓" nor the double click to add the date/timestamp seems to do anything. I know I had the individual VBA codes I originally posted working however the merging of them does not appear to have worked.

Comment: It does work, I modified my answer to add a gif.

Comment: Thank you so much. Not sure what I did. I may have missed something when I was copying the code across, but I have tried it again and it is working perfectly. Thank you!

Comment: I do have one other request for an enhancement if it is possible. In column H2:H600 where I double click to add a "✓", would it be possible to add a date/timestamp in the same row in column Z2:Z600 when the "✓" is inserted? I only need this for the ticks in column H2:H600 and not for all the cells where I use double click to add a "✓".

Comment: Of course you can. I couldn't fit the code in the comment, so I posted another answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo ErrorRoutine
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("L2:L600,Y2:Y600")) Is Nothing Then
    If Target = "" Then
        Target = Now
    End If
    Cancel = True
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("M2:V600")) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
    End If
    Cancel = True
ElseIf Not Intersect(Target, Range("H2:H600")) Is Nothing Then
    If ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713) Then
        ActiveCell.ClearContents
    Else
        ActiveCell.Value = ChrW(&H2713)
        Target.Offset(0, 18) = Now
    End If
    Cancel = True
End If
Application.EnableEvents = True
Exit Sub
ErrorRoutine:
Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```

[image]